# Advanced HMI Subscribe has null-pointer to m_SynchronizingObject

Tags: c#, wpf

I am getting a error when trying to subscribe. The m_Plc.Read functions is working perfectly, but is going too slow for my application.

this is my code:

```
private AdvancedHMIDrivers.EthernetIPforCLXCom m_Plc;
public MainPageViewModel()
{
   m_Plc = new EthernetIPforCLXCom();
   m_Plc.IPAddress = m_IPAddress;
   m_Plc.ProcessorSlot = Convert.ToInt32(m_ProcessorSlot);
   m_Plc.ComError += DoOnCommError;
   m_Plc.SubscriptionError += DoOnCommError;
   string testString = m_Plc.Read("MyTag");  
   int index = m_Plc.Subscribe("MyTag", 1, 2000, testPlcReaded);
}
private void testPlcReaded(object sender, MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.Drivers.Common.PlcComEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Values[0]);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
}
```

and this is the error I am getting:

> m_SynchronizingObject.BeginInvoke(SubscriptionList(i).dlgCallBack, z)

which is in the folder: EthernetIPforCLXCom.vb.

there is a null-pointer to m_SynchronizingObject.

Error-details:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=AdvancedHMIDrivers
  StackTrace:
       at AdvancedHMIDrivers.EthernetIPforCLXCom.DataLinkLayer_DataReceived(Object sender, PlcComEventArgs e) in C:\prj\TLLAB\TLLAB\AdvancedHMIBeta363 (1)\AdvancedHMIDrivers\EthernetIPforCLXCom.vb:line 1269
       at MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.Drivers.CIP.OnDataReceived(PlcComEventArgs e)
       at MfgControl.AdvancedHMI.Drivers.CIP.DataReceivedEIP(Object sender, PlcComEventArgs e)
```

Comment: You probably should instantiate your object, like:
private AdvancedHMIDrivers.EthernetIPforCLXCom m_Plc = new EthernetIPforCLXCom();

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a bug to me in the current version

The code check if the SynchronizingObject is null or if its handle is created before calling it, so in case it is null, it just crash

```
If m_SynchronizingObject Is Nothing OrElse DirectCast(m_SynchronizingObject, Windows.Forms.Control).IsHandleCreated Then
    '...<some code>...

    m_SynchronizingObject.BeginInvoke(SubscriptionList(i).dlgCallBack, z)
End If
```

You should submit a bug as it probably should look like this

```
If m_SynchronizingObject IsNot Nothing AndAlso DirectCast(m_SynchronizingObject, Windows.Forms.Control).IsHandleCreated Then
    '...<some code>...

    m_SynchronizingObject.BeginInvoke(SubscriptionList(i).dlgCallBack, z)
Else
    '...<some other code>...
End If
```

Edit: I posted this to [the project site on Sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/p/advancedhmi/discussion/875091/thread/1239bb8f/?limit=25) and Archie already solved the issue for the next release

Answer (score 0):

You are not instantiating your object. It is null when you try to use it.
This should help :

```
private EthernetIPforCLXCom m_Plc = new EthernetIPforCLXCom
 {
   IPAddress = m_IPAddress,
   ProcessorSlot = Convert.ToInt32(m_ProcessorSlot),
   ComError += DoOnCommError,
   SubscriptionError += DoOnCommError
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! I copied it wrong from visual studio and I already had changed that by myself. So I still have the same error. :(

Comment: Are m_IPAddress and m_ProcessorSlot instantiated ?

Comment: Yes, they are defined and instantiated. The plc.Read() is working perfectly fine, so the plc is good instantiated.